Creating a subdirectory on GoDaddy
I have a domain on GoDaddy "mydomain.dev". I also created a coding project that I am hosting on Vercel. Is there a way for me to create a subdirectory on GoDaddy to be mydomain.dev/project? Most guides talk about subdomain "project.mydomain.dev" but that's not what I'm looking for.
I know that I can create a route by editing my domain and creating a link path. But wondering if it can be done strictly on GoDaddy without editing the source code for my website.
